# How do I increase the rate limit for Google translate API?

Tags: google-translate, quota

I am getting a HTTP 403 error with message: "... returned "User Rate Limit Exceeded">. after about 5K message translation. I have a deadline to get this done and the forum postings are not getting any responses from Google support.

The FAQ page states the following:

*I get an HTTP 403 error when I call the API.
You may be exceeding your quota: either the daily billable total, or the limit on request characters per second.
To view or change usage limits for your project, or to request an increase to your quota, open the API Library in the Cloud Platform Console.
If you have enabled billing for your project, you can see the quota percentage for each API. You can view and change quotas from the API section's API Library and Enabled APIs links*
======================*

I have my rate at the maximum allowable which is 10K/100sec/user, I cannot increase past that.

`characters/100seconds/user  10,000`

And when I go to the quota request page to ask Google support to increase it, the only thing I see is the character increase request, not the rate increase, and it does not let me submit the form.

How do I get someone at Google to look at this without paying $300 for silver support - that is the lowest level at which they provide phone support.

===============

*Translate API Quota Increase Request
This form should be used by customers of Google Cloud Platform for the following:
Owners of applications that wish to increase quota limit of Translate API to higher than 50M characters/day
If you wish to increase your quota, but will stay below 50M characters/day, please follow the steps listed on the Translate API FAQ page.
If you have other questions related to Translate API, please check this public forum for further help.

=================

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for Google's support instead of being directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer back from Google - you need to input 51 or greater into the request form (not 51M which I was trying and the form would just not let me submit).

At the current rate, my program will take about 8 hours to run if I put in the right timing delays, and I cannot monitor my program...hoping Google will increase the rate quota

`If seems you're hitting the characters/100seconds/user quota. Currently there isn't any separate form to request an increase to this specific quota. You can request an increase by filling out the Translate API Quota Increase Request form. You'll need to specify 'Approximate translate volume (M characters/day)' as anything > 50 (e.g. 51) to get past the form validation. Inside 'Detailed description of API Usage' section, please explain in details that you need an increase to the characters/100seconds/user quota (along with desired increase) and not to characters/day.`